# HTMLUnit hangs/infinite loop on javascript exception

Tags: java, scala, htmlunit, rhino

This is about HTMLUnit v2.24.
On hitting this [URL](http://www.lordandtaylor.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/lord-and-taylor/two-piece-suit-0320-lhey21rz1351--1),
The following exception is observed after which `HTMLUnit` does not proceed. It just consumes full CPU and huge memory beyond that point.

```
1. setThrowExceptionOnScriptError - false
2. setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode - false
3. setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode - false


START=================

WARNING: warning: message=[RHINO USAGE WARNING: Missed Context.javaToJS() conversion:
Rhino runtime detected object com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking set of class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException where it expected String, Number, Boolean or Scriptable instance. Please check your code for missing Context.javaToJS() call.] sourceName=[script in http://www.lordandtaylor.com/main/ProductDetail.jsp?prd_code=0500072284565 from (45, 33) to (48, 11)] line=[46] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
RHINO USAGE WARNING: Missed Context.javaToJS() conversion:
Rhino runtime detected object com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking set of class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException where it expected String, Number, Boolean or Scriptable instance. Please check your code for missing Context.javaToJS() call.
Jun 29, 2017 8:34:43 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine handleJavaScriptException
INFO: Caught script exception
======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[java.lang.RuntimeException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking set
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:892)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:774)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:750)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:975)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:772)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:729)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1209)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:207)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:337)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3137)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2100)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:927)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:506)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:459)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:979)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:273)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:161)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:387)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:305)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:452)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:437)
    at main.htmlUnit$.pageText(htmlUnit.scala:18)
    at main.ParTest$.fetchPage(ParTest.scala:36)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParTest.scala:60)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ParTest.scala:59)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ParTest.scala:59)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$launch$2.apply(ParTest.scala:27)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$launch$2.apply(ParTest.scala:26)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking set
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:182)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:448)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:413)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:252)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:765)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:877)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.UniqueTag cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.arrays.ArrayBufferViewBase.set(ArrayBufferViewBase.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
    ... 56 more
Enclosed exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking set
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:182)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:448)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:413)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:252)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:765)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:877)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:774)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:750)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:975)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:772)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:729)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1209)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:207)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:337)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3137)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2100)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:927)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:506)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:459)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:979)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:273)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:161)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:387)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:305)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:452)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:437)
    at main.htmlUnit$.pageText(htmlUnit.scala:18)
    at main.ParTest$.fetchPage(ParTest.scala:36)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParTest.scala:60)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ParTest.scala:59)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ParTest.scala:59)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$launch$2.apply(ParTest.scala:27)
    at main.ParTest$$anonfun$launch$2.apply(ParTest.scala:26)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.UniqueTag cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.arrays.ArrayBufferViewBase.set(ArrayBufferViewBase.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
    ... 56 more
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Comment: Please try with the latest version...

Comment: @RBRi : Thanks, using the latest version of HTMLUnit (2.27) worked. It needs Java 8, though, and we are using Java 7.